# File updated with garbage value when I am tring to update an object record in C++

Tags: c++

**I am trying to create a student record and keep modify student record as one of the option. But for updating I am facing some issue. Here is the code following which I have put the problem.**

```
void modify_student()
            {
                char n[6];
                int found = 0;
                //clrscr();
                cout << "\n\n\tMODIFY STUDENT RECORD";
                cout << "\n\n\tEnter The admission no. of The student";
                cin >> n;
                fp.open("student.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
                while (fp.read((char*)&st, sizeof(student)) && found == 0)
                {
                    if (stricmp(st.retadmno(), n) == 0)
                    {
                        st.show_student();
                        cout << "\nEnter The New Details of student" << endl;
                        st.modify_student();
                        int negIntegral = -1;
                        // int pos = -1 * sizeof(st);
                        long pos = negIntegral * sizeof(st);
                        fp.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
                        fp.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
                        cout << "\n\n\t Record Updated";
                        found = 1;
                    }
                }

                fp.close();
                if (found == 0)
                    cout << "\n\n Record Not Found ";
            //  //getch();
            }
```

> Previosly the File looks like #
>
> ```
>         123 XYZ
> ```
>
> After running the above code to update to modify XYZ to PQR . The
>   File shows
>
> ```
>         1123 PQR 
>              ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
>     and the entr in the file after 1st one is also not properly aligned.
>
>     I am not really understanding what is happening here. Please help
> ```
>
> The Full Code is here #

```
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<process.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class book
{
    char bno[6];
    char bname[50];
    char aname[20];
public:
    void create_book()
    {
        cout << "\nNEW BOOK ENTRY...\n";
        cout << "\nEnter The book no.";
        cin >> bno;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\n\nEnter The Name of The Book ";
        fgets(bname,1234,stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\n\nEnter The Author's Name ";
        fgets(aname, 1234, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\n\n\nBook Created..";
    }

    void show_book()
    {
        cout << "\nBook no. : " << bno;
        cout << "\nBook Name : ";
        puts(bname);
        cout << "Author Name : ";
        puts(aname);
    }

    void modify_book()
    {
        cout << "\nBook no. : " << bno;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\nModify Book Name : ";
        fgets(bname, 1234, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\nModify Author's Name of Book : ";
        fgets(aname, 1234, stdin);
    }
    char* retbno()
    {
        return bno;
    }

    void report()
    {
        cout << bno << setw(30) << bname << setw(30) << aname << endl;
    }


};         //class ends here

class student
{
    char admno[6];
    char name[20];
    char stbno[6];
    int token;
public:
    void create_student()
    {

        cout << "\nNEW STUDENT ENTRY...\n";
        cout << "\nEnter The admission no. ";
        cin >> admno;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "\n\nEnter The Name of The Student ";
        fgets(name, 1234, stdin);
        token = 0;
        stbno[0] = '/0';
        cout << "\n\nStudent Record Created..";
    }

    void show_student()
    {
        cout << "\nAdmission no. : " << admno;
        cout << "\nStudent Name : ";
        puts(name);
        cout << "\nNo of Book issued : " << token;
        if (token == 1)
            cout << "\nBook No " << stbno;
    }

    void modify_student()
    {
        cout << "\nAdmission no. : " << admno;
        cout << "\nModify Student Name : ";
        fgets(name, 1234, stdin);
    }

    char* retadmno()
    {
        return admno;
    }

    char* retstbno()
    {
        return stbno;
    }

    int rettoken()
    {
        return token;
    }

    void addtoken()
    {
        token = 1;
    }

    void resettoken()
    {
        token = 0;
    }

    void fgetstbno(char t[])
    {
        strcpy_s(stbno,256, t);
    }

    void report()
    {
        cout << "\t" << admno << setw(20) << name << setw(10) << token << endl;
    }

};         //class ends here

fstream fp, fp1;
book bk;
student st;




//***************************************************************
//      function to write in file
//****************************************************************

void write_book()
{
    char ch;
    fp.open("book.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
    do
    {
        //clrscr();
        bk.create_book();
        fp.write((char*)&bk, sizeof(book));
        cout << "\n\nDo you want to add more record..(y/n?)";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
    fp.close();
}

void write_student()
{
    char ch;
    fp.open("student.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
    do
    {
        st.create_student();
        fp.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
        cout << "\n\ndo you want to add more record..(y/n?)";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
    fp.close();
}


//***************************************************************
//      function to read specific record from file
//****************************************************************


void display_spb(char n[])
{
    cout << "\nBOOK DETAILS\n";
    int flag = 0;
    fp.open("book.dat", ios::in);
    while (fp.read((char*)&bk, sizeof(book)))
    {
        if (strcmpid(bk.retbno(), n) == 0)
        {
            bk.show_book();
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    fp.close();
    if (flag == 0)
        cout << "\n\nBook does not exist";
    // //getch();
}

void display_sps(char n[])
{
    cout << "\nSTUDENT DETAILS\n";
    int flag = 0;
    fp.open("student.dat", ios::in);
    while (fp.read((char*)&st, sizeof(student)))
    {
        if ((strcmpi(st.retadmno(), n) == 0))
        {
            st.show_student();
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    fp.close();
    if (flag == 0)
        cout << "\n\nStudent does not exist";
//  //getch();
}


//***************************************************************
//      function to modify record of file
//****************************************************************


void modify_book()
{
    char n[6];
    int found = 0;
    //clrscr();
    cout << "\n\n\tMODIFY BOOK REOCORD.... ";
    cout << "\n\n\tEnter The book no. of The book";
    cin >> n;
    fp.open("book.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    while (fp.read((char*)&bk, sizeof(book)) && found == 0)
    {
        if (strcmpid(bk.retbno(), n) == 0)
        {
            bk.show_book();
            cout << "\nEnter The New Details of book" << endl;
            bk.modify_book();
            int negIntegral = -1;
            //int pos = -1 * sizeof(bk);
            long pos = negIntegral * sizeof(bk);
            fp.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
            fp.write((char*)&bk, sizeof(book));
            cout << "\n\n\t Record Updated";
            found = 1;
        }
    }

    fp.close();
    if (found == 0)
        cout << "\n\n Record Not Found ";
//  //getch();
}


void modify_student()
{
    char n[6];
    int found = 0;
    //clrscr();
    cout << "\n\n\tMODIFY STUDENT RECORD... ";
    cout << "\n\n\tEnter The admission no. of The student";
    cin >> n;
    fp.open("student.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    while (fp.read((char*)&st, sizeof(student)) && found == 0)
    {
        if (strcmpid(st.retadmno(), n) == 0)
        {
            st.show_student();
            cout << "\nEnter The New Details of student" << endl;
            st.modify_student();
            int negIntegral = -1;
            // int pos = -1 * sizeof(st);
            long pos = negIntegral * sizeof(st);
            fp.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
            fp.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
            cout << "\n\n\t Record Updated";
            found = 1;
        }
    }

    fp.close();
    if (found == 0)
        cout << "\n\n Record Not Found ";
//  //getch();
}

//***************************************************************
//      function to delete record of file
//****************************************************************


void delete_student()
{
    char n[6];
    int flag = 0;
    //clrscr();
    cout << "\n\n\n\tDELETE STUDENT...";
    cout << "\n\nEnter The admission no. of the Student You Want To Delete : ";
    cin >> n;
    fp.open("student.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    fstream fp2;
    fp2.open("Temp.dat", ios::out);
    fp.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (fp.read((char*)&st, sizeof(student)))
    {
        if (strcmpid(st.retadmno(), n) != 0)
            fp2.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
        else
            flag = 1;
    }

    fp2.close();
    fp.close();
    remove("student.dat");
    rename("Temp.dat", "student.dat");
    if (flag == 1)
        cout << "\n\n\tRecord Deleted ..";
    else
        cout << "\n\nRecord not found";
//  //getch();
}


void delete_book()
{
    char n[6];
    //clrscr();
    cout << "\n\n\n\tDELETE BOOK ...";
    cout << "\n\nEnter The Book no. of the Book You Want To Delete : ";
    cin >> n;
    fp.open("book.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    fstream fp2;
    fp2.open("Temp.dat", ios::out);
    fp.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (fp.read((char*)&bk, sizeof(book)))
    {
        if (strcmpid(bk.retbno(), n) != 0)
        {
            fp2.write((char*)&bk, sizeof(book));
        }
    }

    fp2.close();
    fp.close();
    remove("book.dat");
    rename("Temp.dat", "book.dat");
    cout << "\n\n\tRecord Deleted ..";
//  //getch();
}



//***************************************************************
//      function to display all students list
//****************************************************************

void display_alls()
{
    //clrscr();
    fp.open("student.dat", ios::in);
    if (!fp)
    {
        cout << "ERROR!!! FILE COULD NOT BE OPEN ";
//      //getch();
        return;
    }

    cout << "\n\n\t\tSTUDENT LIST\n\n";
    cout << "==================================================================\n";
    cout << "\tAdmission No." << setw(10) << "Name" << setw(20) << "Book Issued\n";
    cout << "==================================================================\n";

    while (fp.read((char*)&st, sizeof(student)))
    {
        st.report();
    }

    fp.close();
//  //getch();
}


//***************************************************************
//      function to display Books list
//****************************************************************

void display_allb()
{
    //clrscr();
    fp.open("book.dat", ios::in);
    if (!fp)
    {
        cout << "ERROR!!! FILE COULD NOT BE OPEN ";
        //getch();
        return;
    }

    cout << "\n\n\t\tBook LIST\n\n";
    cout << "=========================================================================\n";
    cout << "Book Number" << setw(20) << "Book Name" << setw(25) << "Author\n";
    cout << "=========================================================================\n";

    while (fp.read((char*)&bk, sizeof(book)))
    {
        bk.report();
    }
    fp.close();
    //getch();
}



//***************************************************************
//      function to issue book
//****************************************************************

void book_issue()
{
    char sn[6], bn[6];
    int found = 0, flag = 0;
    //clrscr();
    cout << "\n\nBOOK ISSUE ...";
    cout << "\n\n\tEnter The student's admission no.";
    cin >> sn;
    fp.open("student.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    fp1.open("book.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    while (fp.read((char*)&st, sizeof(student)) && found == 0)
    {
        if (strcmpid(st.retadmno(), sn) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            if (st.rettoken() == 0)
            {
                cout << "\n\n\tEnter the book no. ";
                cin >> bn;
                while (fp1.read((char*)&bk, sizeof(book)) && flag == 0)
                {
                    if (strcmpid(bk.retbno(), bn) == 0)
                    {
                        bk.show_book();
                        flag = 1;
                        st.addtoken();
                        st.fgetstbno(bk.retbno());
                        int negIntegral = -1;
                        long pos = negIntegral * sizeof(st);
                        fp.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
                        fp.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
                        cout << "\n\n\t Book issued successfully\n\nPlease Note: Write current date \
                        in backside of book and submit within 15 days fine Rs. 1 for each day   \
                        after 15 days period";
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 0)
                    cout << "Book no does not exist";
            }
            else
                cout << "You have not returned the last book ";

        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
        cout << "Student record not exist...";
    //getch();
    fp.close();
    fp1.close();
}

void book_deposit()
{
    char sn[6], bn[6];
    int found = 0, flag = 0, day, fine;
    //clrscr();
    cout << "\n\nBOOK DEPOSIT ...";
    cout << "\n\n\tEnter The student’s admission no.";
    cin >> sn;
    fp.open("student.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    fp1.open("book.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
    while (fp.read((char*)&st, sizeof(student)) && found == 0)
    {
        if (strcmpid(st.retadmno(), sn) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            if (st.rettoken() == 1)
            {
                while (fp1.read((char*)&bk, sizeof(book)) && flag == 0)
                {
                    if (strcmpid(bk.retbno(), st.retstbno()) == 0)
                    {
                        bk.show_book();
                        flag = 1;
                        cout << "\n\nBook deposited in no. of days";
                        cin >> day;
                        if (day>15)
                        {
                            fine = (day - 15) * 1;
                            cout << "\n\nFine has to deposited Rs. " << fine;
                        }
                        st.resettoken();
                        int negIntegral = -1;
                        int pos = negIntegral * sizeof(st);
                        fp.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
                        fp.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
                        cout << "\n\n\t Book deposited successfully";
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 0)
                    cout << "Book no does not exist";
            }
            else
                cout << "No book is issued..please check!!";
        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
        cout << "Student record not exist...";
    fp.close();
    fp1.close();
}




//***************************************************************
//      INTRODUCTION FUNCTION
//****************************************************************

void intro()
{
    //clrscr();
    //gotoxy(35,11);
    cout << "LIBRARY";
    //gotoxy(35,14);
    cout << "MANAGEMENT";
    //gotoxy(35,17);
    cout << "SYSTEM";

}



//***************************************************************
//      ADMINISTRATOR MENU FUNCTION
//****************************************************************

void admin_menu()
{
    //clrscr();
    int ch2;
    cout << "\n\n\n\tADMINISTRATOR MENU";
    cout << "\n\n\t1.CREATE STUDENT RECORD";
    cout << "\n\n\t2.DISPLAY ALL STUDENTS RECORD";
    cout << "\n\n\t3.DISPLAY SPECIFIC STUDENT RECORD ";
    cout << "\n\n\t4.MODIFY STUDENT RECORD";
    cout << "\n\n\t5.DELETE STUDENT RECORD";
    cout << "\n\n\t6.CREATE BOOK ";
    cout << "\n\n\t7.DISPLAY ALL BOOKS ";
    cout << "\n\n\t8.DISPLAY SPECIFIC BOOK ";
    cout << "\n\n\t9.MODIFY BOOK ";
    cout << "\n\n\t10.DELETE BOOK ";
    cout << "\n\n\t11.BACK TO MAIN MENU";
    cout << "\n\n\tPlease Enter Your Choice (1-11) ";
    cin >> ch2;
    switch (ch2)
    {
    case 1: //clrscr();
        write_student(); break;
    case 2: display_alls(); break;
    case 3:
        char num[6];
        //clrscr();
        cout << "\n\n\tPlease Enter The Admission No. ";
        cin >> num;
        display_sps(num);
        break;
    case 4: modify_student(); break;
    case 5: delete_student(); break;
    case 6: //clrscr();
        write_book(); break;
    case 7: display_allb(); break;
    case 8: {
        char num[6];
        //clrscr();
        cout << "\n\n\tPlease Enter The book No. ";
        cin >> num;
        display_spb(num);
        break;
    }
    case 9: modify_book(); break;
    case 10: delete_book(); break;
    case 11: return;
    default:cout << "\a";
    }
    admin_menu();
}


//***************************************************************
//      THE MAIN FUNCTION OF PROGRAM
//****************************************************************


void main()
{
    char ch;
    intro();
    do
    {
        //clrscr();
        cout << "\n\n\n\tMAIN MENU";
        cout << "\n\n\t01. BOOK ISSUE";
        cout << "\n\n\t02. BOOK DEPOSIT";
        cout << "\n\n\t03. ADMINISTRATOR MENU";
        cout << "\n\n\t04. EXIT";
        cout << "\n\n\tPlease Select Your Option (1-4) ";
        //ch = getche();
        ch = std::cin.get();
        switch (ch)
        {
        case '1'://clrscr();
            book_issue();
            break;
        case '2':book_deposit();
            break;
        case '3':admin_menu();
            break;
        case '4':exit(0);
        default:cout << "\a";
        }
    } while (ch != '4');

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I can't find any definition of `st` in your code. Is it defined outside of `modify_student`?

Comment: St is of Student type

Comment: What's `strcmpid`?

Comment: Please ignore the d. It  is just  strcmpi. Previously I wrote my own function for comparing two strings .

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be 100% sure as not all code is shown, but my suspect is that `st` is a class instance containing non-trivial objects.

If for example the student class contains an `std::string` object you cannot `fread` or `fwrite` it directly to a disk file.

Comment: I will provide with the full code ...and St is the object of the Student class